# How do you change the background color of man pages?

Tags: macos, colors, zsh, man

Specifically, on OSX, in zsh.

I'd like it when say...

```
man man
```

The background color is a darkish-yellow and the foreground is a charcoal gray/black.  In this way I'm sure I'm looking at a man page and not some output.

I've tried to echo some escape codes before the command...

```
echo -e "\e[31m\e[43m"; man man
```

But I didn't get the desired effect, the background color "sort of" changed, but I get the impression man itself is producing escape codes that are canceling out mine.

I also tried digging around in the man.conf groff and grotty configuration but I didn't find anything, but that doesn't mean it isn't there.

I also thought maybe I could create a custom tty or something and export that but it's not clear to me how that would work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `LESS_TERMCAP_*`s with a function like:

```
man() {
    env \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(printf "\e[1;31m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(printf "\e[1;31m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(printf "\e[0m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(printf "\e[0m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(printf "\e[1;44;33m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(printf "\e[0m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(printf "\e[1;32m") \
    man "$@"
}
```

The above is what I use, and have sourced in my [bashrc](https://github.com/demure/dotfiles).

You can read through [termcap(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/termcap) for more info, but I think `se` and `so` may be the ones you want to set.

Comment: I found the red way to harsh, so I adjusted for blue+white https://gist.github.com/reklis/6250044